# C++ - Deducing type from inherited constructor's arguments for class template

Tags: c++, c++20, template-argument-deduction, class-template

I have a class template that inherits the constructors of the base class template. (As for c++20) Is there a way to deduce the template arguments of the derived class from the constructor arguments of base?

If I specify the type explicitly, that works. Or if I reimplement the constructor and call the constructor of base, that also would work but is there a way to do without that?

```
template<typename T>
struct CTestBase
{
    using Type = T;

    CTestBase() = default;
    CTestBase(T t){}
};

template<typename T>
struct CTestDer : public CTestBase<T>
{
    using CTestBase<T>::CTestBase;
};

void test()
{
    //CTestDer der(int{}); //ERROR
    CTestDer<int> der(int{}); //OK
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a [user-defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides):

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct CTestBase
{
    using Type = T;

    CTestBase() = default;
    CTestBase(T t){}
};

template<typename T>
struct CTestDer : public CTestBase<T>
{
    using CTestBase<T>::CTestBase;
};

template<typename T>
CTestDer(T &&t) -> CTestDer<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

void test()
{
    CTestDer der(int{}); // OK now.
}
```

With a little bit more work it should be possible to:

1. Use a variadic template in the deduction guide
2. Have the deduction guide use `decltype` to construct, using its own deduction guide, the superclass
3. Use a specialization to figure out the superclass's template parameters
4. Use that to construct the subclass, to deduce it

This should handle anything. But this will be a lot of work. For this simple use case, and if it's not expected that the superclass will change much, this would be overkill.

Comment: Thank you! At the end of the day, I will need to rely on knowing what constructors the base has, and define deduction guides for all of them, right? No way to get the type from `Type` alias of the base or something?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was inferring in the second half of my question. Hopefully this explanation, and the link that I included to the reference material, should have everything that's needed to pull this off. Make it a deduction guide with a parameter pack, use `decltype(CTestBase{ std::declval<Args &&>()...})`, and grab its `...::Type`. The End. You can give it a try, and ask a follow-up question if you run into a stumbling block. Something along these lines should work.

Comment: You don't need to deduce a forwarding reference just to have to undo it. The other answer shows a more direct approach.

Answer (score 5):

> but is there a way to do without that?

Yes, just add [user-defined deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for `CTestDer`:

```
template<typename T>
CTestDer(T) -> CTestDer<T>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8zh7bGYq8)